# How to start gnome display manager from root shell in ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, shell, gnome

How do I start the display manager (Gnome) from a bash shell on a Ubuntu system? More specifically, the shell obtained from modified the grub boot commands. It would be nice to use a desktop environment instead a bare shell. I can't just execute /bin/init because that will take me to the login prompt when I am already a root user.

I obtained the shell by modifying the grub commands and changing to rw mode and adding init=/bin/bash.

Are there commands I can run to start gnome and go right into the root desktop?

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: I understand what you're trying to do, but not why - and there's probably a better way to achieve that goal than what you're attempting now ([XY problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)). Without a real init process you have nothing to reap zombie processes - not a good idea in the long run.

Comment: Why not just install Ubuntu normally. It comes with Gnome and it works fine. Ubuntu 18, 20 and 22.

Comment: I already have ubuntu installed. This is for Linux password recovery / cyber pen-testing. I modified grub to bypass authentication, which dropped me into a shell. How do I convert the low-level shell to a gnome GUI? I understand it's not an idea, as I can just reset the user password and log in normally. But what if I am limited on time or can't do multiple restarts?

Comment: I would like to bypass the login process entirely without modifying system files such as /etc/shadow.